# Matching of data from output table

Tags: perl

We need to match certain data element by element that is an output in tabular form obtained on the command prompt.The following is the approach being currently followed wherein the $Var contains the output. Is there an optimal way of doing this without directing the command output to file.

Please share your thoughts.

```
$Var = "iSCSI Storage     LHN StgMgmt Name  IP              Name
==============================================================
0                 Storage_1         15.178.209.194  admin
1                 acct-mgmt         15.178.209.194  storage1
2                 acct-mgmt2        15.178.209.194  storage2";

@tab = split("\n",$Var);
foreach (@tab) {
    next if ($_ !~ /^\d/);
    $_ =~ s/\s+//g;
    $first=0 if($_ =~ /Storage/i && /15.178.209.194/);
    push(@Array, $_); }
```

Comment: You want to process/store the first line like this `'0Storage_115.178.209.194admin'`? Do you realize that 1) you do nothing with `$first`? 2) it's not local to the loop and you never unset it either? It seems to be doing nothing and a `shift @tab` before the loop would work just as well for any special behavior line #1 might get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_ =~ /Storage/i && /15.178.209.194/` is silly. That gets broken up like this: `($_ =~ /Storage/i) && (/15.178.209.194/)`. Either use `$_` consistently or don't - the `//` and `s///` operators automatically operate on `$_`.

Also you should know that in the regex `/15.178.209.194/`, the `.`s are being interpreted as any character. Either escape them or use the `index()` function.

Additionally, I would recommend that you separate each line using `split()`. This allows you to compare each individual column. You can use `split()` with a regex like so: `@array = split(/\s+/, $string);`.

Finally, I'm not really sure what `$first` is for, but I notice that all three sample lines in that input trigger `$first=0` as they all contain that IP and the string "storage".

Comment: Thanks DAN.The answer is really useful for me

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to invoke your script like this:

```
./some_shell_command | perl perl_script.pl
```

What you want to use is the Perl diamond operator `<>`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $first;
my @Array;

for (<>) {
    next unless /^\d/;
    s/\s+/ /g;
    $first = 0 if /Storage/i && /15.178.209.194/;
    push(@Array, $_);
}
```

I've removed the redundant uses of `$_` and fixed your substitution, since you probably don't want to remove all spaces.